# Double-tally in Rails then format for upsert_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upsert

I have a table that looks like this:

```
# CategoryTransaction
category_id, transaction_id, buyer_id, seller_id
```

Both `buyer_id` and `seller_id` refer to the `Person` table (as a `Person` can buy and/or sell). I need to tally the combinations of `[category_id, buyer_id]` and `[category_id, supplier_id]`, and store them in this table so we know how often a given `Person` bought/sold a given `Category`:

```
# CategoryPerson
person_id, category_id, bought_count, sold_count
```

This is what I’ve got so far:

```
# 1. Collect transactions grouped by category:
category_transactions = CategoryTransaction.all.select(:category_id, :buyer_id, :supplier_id).group_by(&:category_id)
# Looks like: { category_id: [CategoryTransaction, …], … }

# 2. Calculate the two sets of tallies:
tallies = category_transactions.collect{ |k,v| [k, v.collect(&:buyer_id).tally, v.collect(&:supplier_id).tally] }
# Looks like: [category_id, { buyer_id: count, buyer2_id: count, … }, { seller_id: count, … }]
```

What I’d like is to get this data into suitable format to do an `upsert_all`, which would look like: `[{ category_id:, person_id:, bought_count: 0, sold_count: 0 }, {…}, …]`, so I can run something like:

```
CategoryPerson.upsert_all( tallies.map{ |cp| { category_id: cp.category_id, person_id: cp.person_id, bought_count: cp.bought_count, sold_count: cp.sold_count } }, unique_by: [:category_id, :person_id])
```

How can I get from my current `category_transactions` or `tallies` to this format for the `upsert_all`?

Comment: What database are you using? I would really define a database view which contains these aggregates  instead of making your Rails application responsible for this. I mean you could use an upsert together with either callbacks or a scheduled job but this is the most ineffective way to solve simple reporting possible.

Comment: @max PostgreSQL 14.